# SQL Server - Find max and min records in single query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have following tables

```
CREATE TABLE Patient
(
patientID int,
firstName varchar(50) NOT NULL,
middleName varchar(50),
surName varchar(50) NOT NULL,
p_age int NOT NULL,
p_gender char(1),
p_address varchar(200),
p_contact_no int,
medicalHistory varchar(500),
allergies varchar(200),
CONSTRAINT PK_Patient PRIMARY KEY (patientID)
);

CREATE TABLE Appointment
(
appID int,
patientId int,
staffId int,
appDateTime DateTime,
CONSTRAINT PK_Appointment PRIMARY KEY (appID),
CONSTRAINT FK_Appointment_Patient FOREIGN KEY (patientId) REFERENCES Patient(patientID) ON DELETE CASCADE,
CONSTRAINT FK_Appointment_Staff FOREIGN KEY (staffId) REFERENCES Staff(staffID) ON DELETE CASCADE,
CONSTRAINT CHK_AppointmentDate CHECK (appDateTime>=GETDATE())
);
```

I want to get the records of patients with most and least overall appointments

This is what I have so far. But this returns duplicate records. Other than that the query is fine.

```
WITH s
     AS (SELECT p.patientId, p.firstName,
                Count(a.appId)              AS [Count],
                MAX(Count(a.appId)) OVER () AS [MaxMyGroup],
                MIN(Count(a.appId)) OVER () AS [MinMyGroup]
         FROM   Patient p INNER JOIN Appointment a ON p.patientID = a.patientId
         GROUP  BY p.patientId, p.firstName)
SELECT patientId AS ID,
       firstName AS 'First Name',
       V.[Count] AS 'Appointment Count',
       Agg AS 'MAX/MIN'
FROM   s
CROSS APPLY (VALUES ( 'Most', CASE WHEN [Count] = [MaxMyGroup] THEN [Count] END),
                     ('Least', CASE WHEN [Count] = [MinMyGroup] THEN [Count] END))
             V(Agg, [Count])
WHERE V.[Count] IS NOT NULL
```

Here is my current output. If I could eliminate the duplicates, it would be great.

```
1   Paul    1   Most
1   Paul    1   Least
2   Dwayne  1   Most
2   Dwayne  1   Least
3   Brock   1   Most
3   Brock   1   Least
4   Chris   1   Most
4   Chris   1   Least
5   Melanie 1   Most
5   Melanie 1   Least
6   Kate    1   Most
6   Kate    1   Least
7   James   1   Most
7   James   1   Least
8   Bill    1   Most
8   Bill    1   Least
9   James   1   Most
9   James   1   Least
```

Comment: How are you defining "duplicate"?

Comment: Could you post your expected output? It's not clear to me what you're trying to achieve

Comment: There are no duplicates in your output.

Comment: Can you provide a set of sample data?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you are using `apply`.  A simple `case` seems sufficient:

```
with s as (
      select p.patientId, p.firstName,
             Count(*) as cnt,
             max(Count(*)) over () as maxcnt,
             min(Count(*)) over () AS mincnt
      from Patient p join
           Appointment a
           on p.patientID = a.patientId
      group by p.patientId, p.firstName
     )
select s.*,
       (case when cnt = maxcnt then 'Most'
             when cnt = mincnt then 'Least'
        end) as agg
from s
where cnt in (maxcnt, mincnt);
```

Comment: This is the output of this.

Comment: 1 Paul 1 1 1 Most
2 Dwayne 1 1 1 Most
3 Brock 1 1 1 Most
4 Chris 1 1 1 Most
5 Melanie 1 1 1 Most
6 Kate 1 1 1 Most
7 James 1 1 1 Most
8 Bill 1 1 1 Most
9 James 1 1 1 Most